# Can we be as even handed and quick at reopening questions as we are at closing them?

Tags: discussion, questions

Can we be as even handed and quick at reopening questions as we are at closing them?

I think that would sort out a vast amount of umbrage about high rep users.

Comment: Sure, when the questions warrant it.

Comment: stop being such a badass @curiousdannii this is a community as well as a product. and anyway, if the close reason is no longer (even handed) applicable, then the question should be reopened

Comment: Sounds reasonable on the face if it. Will turn out unreasonable when we ask it statistically: count close-votes Vs open-votes